# Crystal report-how to sum suppressed field in details section?

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have looked on google and there is a lot about summing up fields that are not suppressed but I can't find anything for my specific problem.

I have an invoice report which I want to have let's say 3 lines 2 of those lines are products and 1 of those lines is freight however I do not want to show the freight line on the report. therefore I have put in the below suppressing formula to take it out however this has resulted in me not able to sum up the suppressed field.

```
{invoice.itemType} = "E"
```

the reason I want to do this is that we don't want to see it on the lines report however we want the total freight to be summed up on the footer of the report.

.net runtime version of the crystal addon:- v2.0.50727
Version :- 13.0.3500.0

Could anyone help me with this question?

Comment: Where did you put your suppression formula? If into section expert (for any kind of section), then this should not affect CR summing in any way. If into record selection, then this is just wrong place.

Comment: hi, it is in the section expert part of the report.

Comment: What exactly means `not able to sum up the ... field`?

Comment: meaning it doesn't take into account the suppressed values, however i needed it to. i ended up creating a subreport in an above footer section and passing over the sumed value but not really ideal but its a good enough work around for now. if you could make it any easier than that would be great. i just thought i had missed something.

Comment: Sorry, what is `it`? :) You can create summaries in many ways. Easiest is to sum over field value, this should include suppressed values. Then you can sum over formulaes - result depends on formula evaluation time; if formula can evaluated while reading records, then it should include suppressed values, if formula evaluates while printing records (either `whileprintingreocrds();` is specified or any aggregation function is included or formula depends on any similar late-evaluated formula), then it skips suppressed records.

Comment: but whilereadingrecords cant sum formulas?

Comment: Depend on formula evaluation time. If formulas can be evaluated at first pass (while reading records), then they can be summed too. Summaries itself become available only at second pass (while printing records) and can not be used at first pass. Sorry, my lack of english skills makes explaining hard.

Answer (score 0):

Create a detail-level formula such as this:

```
IF {invoice.itemType} = "E" THEN {Freight} ELSE 0
```

Then, Sum that formuala.